# Clearing line in vi mode deletes the line above

Tags: zsh

I run zsh in VI mode with a two-line prompt.  Whenever I clear the line using 'cc' a line above my prompt is deleted.  E.g. if I start with

```
magnus@tatooine 2502  ~
[I] % 
magnus@tatooine 2502  ~
[I] %
```

Then I press escape and 'cc' I get

```
magnus@tatooine 2502  ~
magnus@tatooine 2502  ~
[I] %
```

It's very repeatable; I can clear the terminal by repeating the sequence multiple times.  What do I need to do to get ZSH to clear the line without deleting the line above it?

My prompt is created using the following

```
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' enable git hg svn
zstyle ':vcs_info:(git*|hg*)' get-revision true
zstyle ':vcs_info:(git*|hg*)' check-for-changes true

zstyle ':vcs_info:git*' formats "(%s: %12.12i %c%u %b)" # hash changes branch
zstyle ':vcs_info:git*' actionformats "(%s(%F{yellow}%a%f): %12.12i %c%u %b)"
zstyle ':vcs_info:hg*:*' branchformat "%b" # only show branch

zstyle ':vcs_info:(hg*|git*):*' stagedstr "%F{green}S%f"
zstyle ':vcs_info:(hg*|git*):*' unstagedstr "%F{red}U%f"

zstyle ':vcs_info:git*+set-message:*' hooks git-st git-stash git-untracked

# improve the ZSH prompt in vi mode
function zle-line-init zle-keymap-select {
    case ${KEYMAP} in
        (main) prompt_vi_mode="%F{yellow}[I]%f"
            ;;
        (vicmd) prompt_vi_mode="%F{red}[N]%f"
            ;;
    esac

    prompt_line1="%F{green}%n@%m%f %F{red}%h%f ${vcs_info_msg_0_} %F{blue}%~%f"
    prompt_line2="${prompt_vi_mode} %B%#%b "
    PS1="${prompt_line1}${prompt_newline}${prompt_line2}"
    zle reset-prompt
}
zle -N zle-line-init
zle -N zle-keymap-select
```

Comment: What version of `zsh` are you using? I had a similar issue with 5.0.2 when using multi-line prompts and `zle reset-prompt`. It went away after upgrading to 5.0.5 (and higher).

Comment: Looking at the package history in ArchLinux I've been running 5.0.7 since a few months back, so the behaviour I ask about is present in that version.  In the meantime I've switched from a multiline prompt, instead I print the first line and can then get away with a single-line prompt.

Comment: I, too, use zsh 5.0.7 on Arch. If I run your code on a prestine *zsh* (that is, started with `zsh -f`) - and set `prompt_newline`, I cannot reproduce that behaviour. Running `cc` in vicmd mode on a empty line does not even leave vicmd mode. Although, for some reason, pressing *Alt+a* (`^[a`) seems to lead to the same phenomenon. That is rather strange because running `bindkey` it seems that `^[a` is not even set.

Comment: Hmm, strange.  The behaviour is definitely there when I run `zsh` normally.  But running `zsh -f`, and `autoload -U promptinit; promptinit` followed by setting `PS1` to something containing `prompt_newline` also leaves me in a shell where `cc` isn't defined in *vicmd* mode.  I do wonder what I'm pulling in that triggers the undesired behaviour.

Comment: Is this question still relevant? Can it be closed?